# R: column and row indices with largest values

Tags: r, matrix, indices

Suppose we have a matrix that looks as follows:

```
-0.3  0.2   0.001  -0.4    0.5 
0.25  0.45  0.2    -0.001  0.02
0.8 - 0.2   0.35   0.1     0.1
0.25 -0.14  -0.1   0.02    0.4
```

Now I want to find that part of the matrix which has dimension 2 x 2 AND has the largest elements (in absolute values) in it. 
So here this would be the following indices:

```
2 1
2 2
3 1 
3 2
```

because

```
0.25 0.4
0.8  -0.2
```

is that part of the matrix which has the largest values of ALL the 2 x 2 matrices in this matrix.

How can I implement this in R?

I've made this little example, because my real matrix contains about 4000 columns and 5000 rows, but many values in this matrix are almost zero. This is difficult to visualize, so for that reason I would like to only visualize the most important ones.

Comment: Do you mean to have a 0.45 rather than 0.4 in your desired output?

Comment: Yes, it would like to have the 2 x 2 matrix with the largest sum (working with absolute values) of elements in it.

Comment: Hope the below helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `which` to find the indices of the maximum for your matrix.

```
set.seed(1234)
mat <- matrix(sample(1:20), ncol = 5)
mat
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    3   14    8   20   17
# [2,]   12   10    6   15   16
# [3,]   11    1    7    2   19
# [4,]   18    4    5    9   13

which(mat == max(mat), arr.ind = TRUE)
#      row col
# [1,]   1   4
```

If you are looking for the maximum in each column (or row) you can use:

```
apply(mat, 2, which.max)
# [1] 4 1 1 1 3
```

**EDIT AFTER QUESTION CLARIFICATION**

```
mrow <- nrow(mat); mcol <- ncol(mat)
subs <- list()
for (i in 1:(nrow(mat) - 1)) {
  for (j in 1:(ncol(mat) - 1)) {
    x <- c(i, j, i, j + 1, i + 1, j, i + 1, j + 1)
    subs[[paste0(i, j)]] <- matrix(x, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
  }
}

sums <- sapply(subs, function (x) sum(abs(mat[x]))) 
win <- subs[[which(sums == max(sums))]]
mat[win[1, 1]:(win[1, 1] + 1), win[1, 2]:(win[1, 2] + 1)]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   20   17
# [2,]   15   16
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's not an exact answer to my question. I would like that part of the matrix mat, a 2 x 2 -matrix, which has the largest values

Answer (score 2):

The package [`RcppRoll`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppRoll/index.html) provides fast rolling sum functions that may help. Here is an answer than runs fast on a large matrix :

```
n <- matrix(rnorm(4000*5000),nrow=4000,ncol=5000)


find_idx_max_square <- function(matrix) {
  library(RcppRoll)
  o <- apply(abs(matrix), 2,roll_suml,n=2L)
  p <- t(apply(o, 1,roll_suml,n=2L))
  idx <- which(p == max(p,na.rm=TRUE),arr.ind=TRUE)
  return(idx)
}

find_idx_max_square(n)
      row col
[1,] 1837 724

> system.time(find_idx_max_square(n))
utilisateur     système      écoulé 
  1.863          0.159       2.023
```

**Explanation**

1. Take a matrix `matrix`
2. Compute the rolling sum of all succeeding two elements for each column (`matrix[i,j] + matrix[i+1,j]` for `i` in `nrow(matrix)` and `j` in `ncol(matrix)`). Store it in a new matrix `o`
3. Compute the rolling sum of all succeeding two elements on each row on each column (`matrix[i,j] + matrix[i,j+1]` for `i` in `nrow(matrix)` and `j` in `ncol(matrix)`). Store it in a new matrix `p`.
4. `p` has in each cell `[i,j]` the sum of value `[i,j]`, `[i+1,j]`, `[i,j+1]`,`[i+1,j+1]` of the original `matrix`
5. compute the maximum value of `p`. It gives us the index of the upper left value of the 2*2 submatrix with the maximum sum.

Answer (score 1):

I will be quite slow but does the job, this will give the row and column indexes of the wanted submatrix:

```
library(magrittr)

df = expand.grid(seq(nrow(mat)-1), seq(ncol(mat)-1)) 

vec = apply(df, 1, function(u){
              mat[u[1]:(u[1]+1),u[2]:(u[2]+1)] %>%
              abs %>%
              sum
      }) 

ind = df[which.max(vec),]
mat[ind[[1]]:(ind[[1]]+1),ind[[2]]:(ind[[2]]+1)]

#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]   20   17
#[2,]   15   16
```

Where `mat` is:

```
mat = structure(c(3L, 12L, 11L, 18L, 14L, 10L, 1L, 4L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 
5L, 20L, 15L, 2L, 9L, 17L, 16L, 19L, 13L), .Dim = 4:5)
```